# iOSのUIViewControllerにtableViewを追加する場合

Tags: ios, tableview

UITableViewControllerを使って`cellForRowAtIndexPath`等を定義してtableを表示していましたが、
table以外のモノも表示したいためstoryboadでViewControllerの中にtableViewを配置したものに変更しました。

この場合、`self.tableView`に対して`cellForRowAtIndexPath`や`numberOfSectionsInTableView`はどうやって設定したらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

対象となるViewControllerで、`UITableViewDelegate`と`UITableViewDataSource`を実装すればいいと思います。

- https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html
- https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html

その上で、

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

[image: アウトレットを定義]

とViewController.hにアウトレットをつなげたうえで、

[image: dataSourceとdelegateを設定]

dataSourceとdelegateをViewControllerにすればいいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

上の回答で尽きているが、UITableViewDataSourceというプロトコルが、それらのメソッドを規定している。
そのプロトコルを必要としているのは、UITableView.　UITableViewは、それらのメソッドがどこにあるのか、しるのに、datasource というプロパティを持っている

UITableViewControllerをstoryboardに貼りつけた場合や、UiTableViewControllerのサブクラス・ソースをxibつきで生成した場合、storyboardや、xibのなかに、フリーズドライされた形で、UITableViewに、datasource の値が、設定されているので、この設定は、やる必要がない。

今回のようなことをやる場合、上の回答にある、datasourceを設定する以外に、

ViewController.h で、

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
```

と、このViewControllerが、UITableViewDataSourceプロトコルを実装していることを明示する必要がある。