# UIViewController で UITableView の Delegate を呼び出すには?

Tags: ios, objective-c

ストーリーボードを使わずに下記のようなコードを使用し、 UIViewController 内部で UITableView の Delegate を呼び出したいです。

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200);
    tableView.tag = 1;
    tableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - TableView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"2");
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"3");
    return cell;
}

@end
```

ヘッダファイルは以下のようになっています。

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

デリゲートを設定しているはずなのにデリゲートメソッドが呼び出されないのはなぜなのでしょうか？

[iOSのUIViewControllerにtableViewを追加する場合](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/306/ios%E3%81%AEuiviewcontroller%E3%81%ABtableview%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)
似たような投稿がありましたがストーリボードを使用せずにコードのみで実装したいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    tableView.tag = 1;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self; // 追加
}
```

UITableViewのDelegateには、UITableViewDelegateプロトコルと、**UITableViewDataSource**プロトコルの2種類があって、メソッド「- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView」、「-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section」、「- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath」は、**UITableViewDataSource**プロトコルに属していますから、「tableView.dataSource = self;」がないと、Delegateの受け手にならないのです。